# htaccess for optional values

Tags: .htaccess

i have this simple htacces rule

```
RewriteRule ^entreprise-edit-(.*)-?(.*)?$  entreprise-edit.php?e_token=$1&edit=$2 [L]
```

so what i want is to have this part: `-?(.*)?`  optional but it does not work i get a 404 error,
the rewrite rule only works when the optional part `-?(.*)?` is not in use when querying the page.

Comment: .* encompasses "-" . Can you try with ^entreprise-edit-([^-]*)-?(.*)?$

Comment: Have added as an answer, you can mark it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.* encompasses "-" .

You can use ^entreprise-edit-([^-]*)-?(.*)?$

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your rule is that even when you include the second query parameter it's matched by the first (.+) (greedy match) .

i think your cms is producing the 404 Error because the e_token is not valid

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^entreprise-edit-(.+?)(-.+)?$  entreprise-edit.php?e_token=$1&edit=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i need to learn some more htaccess.